# Is there a canonical resource for the classification of Judo mat techniques?

Tags: technique, judo, grappling, terminology, identification

For throws, I use Toshiro Daigo's book *Kodokan Judo Throwing Techniques* published by Kodanasha International, Tokyo 2005. It specifically addresses some of the arcane points of Kodokan classification that distinguish what is considered one throw versus another. This book is [mostly up to date](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/8534/5961). Is there a similar canonical resource that covers mat (pins, chokes, armlocks) techniques? For example, I was just informed that [*ude garami* can be done against a straight arm](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/9083/5961). I previously would have called that an *ude hishigi ude gatame*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the materials published by the Kodokan, the two which describe the classification of Katame-waza in most detail are:

- [*Kodokan Judo: The Essential Guide to Judo by Its Founder Jigoro Kano*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Kodokan_Judo.html?id=AVn9nQEACAAJ) (1997)
- [*Kodokan Judo Katame Waza: Various techniques and their names*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFMgFnvHZMs) (1994) (video)

Both works demonstrate and list the points of distinction of each technique and their common variations. The video series demonstrates the straight arm variant of *ude-garami*. While Kano's book includes examples of three variations of *ude-garami*, it unfortunately does not include the straight arm variant.

Note however that Kano doesn't claim that the examples in this text are exhaustive, making the following caveat:

> The katame waza introduced here are the ones **most frequently used** in randori and competition.

---

<sup>**History of Kodokan Katame-waza classification:**</sup>

<sup>**01/02/1985:** Adds classifications for</sup>
     <sup>• *Sode-guruma-jime, Kata-te-jime, Ryo-te-jime, Tsukkomi-jime, Sankaku-jime*</sup>
     <sup>• *Ude-hishigi-ashi-gatame, Ude-hishigi-te-gatame, Ude-hishigi-sankaku-gatame*</sup>
<sup>**01/04/1997:** Renames *hon-kesa-gatame* to *kesa-gatame*</sup>
<sup>**01/04/2017:** Adds classifications *Ushiro-kesa-gatame, Uki-gatame, Ura-gatame*</sup>

Comment: *Canon of Judo* is a good example of the messiness of technique identification. The technique called body armlock (*ude-hisihigi-tai-gatame*) on page 151 is currently called *ude-hisihigi-waki-gatame* in most places. I do not expect resources to agree always.

Comment: More frustration on the classification of ude garami versus ude gatame: Techniques of Judo by Shinzo Takagaki and Harold (Hal) Sharp shows the ude garami arm configuration against a straight arm as ude gatame, not ude garami. Also amusing is that Hal Sharp appears to have posted the YouTube Kodokan Katame Waza video.

Comment: @mattm even Neil Adams refers to armbar *ude-garami* as an *ude-gatame*: [Grand Prix Zagreb 2017 | 78kg | Hamada vs. Camara](https://youtu.be/OpNbN5ko52I&t=2920)