# How are the clock choke and bow-and-arrow choke classified in Judo?

Tags: judo, technique, chokes

The canonical form of *okuri-eri-jime* refers to chokes where one lapel is held with the inside of the wrist against uke's neck, and the other is pulled taught to apply the strangle. The canonical *kata-te-jime* is applied using only one hand holding the collar applying pressure to the trachea with the outside of the wrist.

However I'm unsure how certain competitive chokes should be classified (e.g. clock choke, bow-and-arrow choke) - they are blood chokes using the inside of the wrist grabbing the lapel (like in *okuri-eri-jime*), but they are applied holding only one lapel (like *kata-te-jime*).

The kodokan considers *jigoku-jime* a variant fo *okuri-eri-jime*, which would seem to imply these other chokes are too, since they are mechanically similar.

How does the kodokan classify these techniques?

Comment: This is another example of why I was looking for a [canonical newaza resource](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/9086/5961). I was looking at a copy of Kashiwazaki's Shimewaza book the other day, and I remember these were in it, but not what they were called. Would you consider this a Kodokan classification?

Comment: @mattm unfortunately Kashiwazaki's *Fighting Judo* doesn't give classifications for these chokes - he calls them *koshi-jime* and *shime-waza* (counter to *ippon-seoi-nage*) respectively.

Comment: Koshi jime isn't a classification?

Comment: @mattm ah, I meant under one of the [12 recognised classifications](http://kodokanjudoinstitute.org/en/waza/list/#a2-3) - it could of course not come under any of them and be a novel type of technique in the Kodokan's eyes. [Here](https://youtu.be/Htm2UDhEC_Y?t=4616) is a video series by Kashiwazaki illustrating his ne-waza techniques, haven't watched all of it myself yet, he might elucidate here.

Comment: It's interesting that kagato-jime (or any kind of ashi-jime) is not recognised. Probably because it is so obscure and relatively low percentage.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking *Kagato-jime* is considered a variant of [*hadaka-jime*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvOMQl1Qmow&feature=youtu.be&t=369), officially.

Comment: I would actually not call this kagato-jime. It may be just me, but kagato-jime is from guard, holding and pulling both lapels, having the ankle in front of uke's neck pushing. That wouldn't qualify for hadaka since the gi is used.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking true, this is kind of an 'inverted' version, with the forearm applying the pressure as opposed to the shin. But given the Kodokan calls this hadaka-jime, I presume the more usual [gogoplata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gogoplata) version is also such. I'm not sure how the version you describe (pulling the lapels, as in Mikonosuke Kawaishi's book My Method of Judo) would be classified.

Comment: Well, in the quite peculiar German nomenclature, it's simply a ashi-jime technique ;)

Answer (score 2):

What the second hand in okuri-eri-jime does is securing the shoulder, even if it does so holding the lapel. That is why jigoku-jime is considered okuri-eri: one limb is securing the shoulder, one hand is closing around the neck.

Since clock choke (or koshi-jime) does the same, it has to be considered a variant of okuri-eri-jime.

Regarding bow-and-arrow, it's the same: since the shoulder is the fixed counter-point, it is okuri-eri-jime.

Kata-te-jime is without active fixation, it can basically only be performed against the ground from above, or against a *passive* part of the body behind uke's neck.

Official classifications are hard to find, therefore this is derived purely from the underlying principles of the chokes as demonstrated in katame-no-kata.

Answer (score 1):

## *Koshi-jime* (okuri-eri-jime)

According to the *Kodokan Judo Video Series*, Vol. 3 - [Katame Waza: Various Techniques and their Names](https://youtu.be/yvOMQl1Qmow?t=487), the "clock choke" is considered a variant of *okuri-eri-jime*, irrespective of whether the second lapel is held.

This is affirmed in [柔道大事典](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/%E6%9F%94%E9%81%93%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%8B%E5%85%B8.html?id=TkS_AAAACAAJ) (p.173), where this choke is referred to as *koshi-jime*. It also known as *yoko-jime*, or *yoko-okuri-eri-jime*. In 1995, the IJF classified *koshi-jime* as a distinct technique, but in 1998 ammended its classification to align with the Kodokan.

## *"Bow-and-arrow choke"* (okuri-eri-jime / kata-te-jime)

When used in competition, the "bow-and-arrow choke" is consistently classified as *okuri-eri-jime* by the IJF:

- [2014 Asian Games | 52kg | Nakamura vs Jung](http://www.judo.or.jp/p/32969)
- [2018 Grand Prix | 66kg | Maruyama vs Jurakik](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/15144/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gp_chn2018_m_0066_0050)
- [2019 Grand Slam | 66kg | JoShiro vs Biel](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/15144/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_ger2019_m_0066_0063)

While the AJJF coincided with the IJF in the above, they/the Kodokan Cup differed in the following examples, classifying them *kata-te-jime*:

- [2018 World Championships | 63kg | Tashiro vs Tremblay](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/3637/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2018_w_0063_0055)
- [2015 World Championships | 66kg | Ebinuma vs Cesar](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/1787/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2015_m_0066_0013)
- [2018 Kodokan Cup | 48kg | Koga vs Yamazaki](https://seikosportslink.com/dev/judo/results.html?i=12018012&s=JU&d=JU&g=W&e=048&c=01)
- [2017 Grand Prix | 100kg Wolf vs Nikiforofu](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/1787/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2015_m_0066_0013)

So it seems that this style of choke is indeed ambiguous, at least in Japan.

## *"Canto choke"* (Kata-te-kata-ashi-jime)

This ambiguity can also be seen in the "Canto choke", which in Japan appears to generally be considered a variant of *kata-te-jime* ([柔道 固技教本](https://books.apple.com/gb/book/%E5%B0%8F%E5%AE%A4%E5%AE%8F%E4%BA%8C-%E6%9F%94%E9%81%93%E5%9B%BA%E6%8A%80%E6%95%99%E6%9C%AC/id986257130)), but has been labelled *okuri-eri-jime* by the IJF in competition:

- [2018 Grand Slam | 78kg | Apotekaru vs Cardenas](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/13608/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_ger2018_w_0078_0024)

Comment: I think the ambiguity comes from whether it is an active fixation of the shoulder, or a one-handed choke against a passive thigh. Depending on whether one or the other is more prominent, you technically end up with a different classification.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Looking at the Kodokan shime-waza video, it seems the [two variants of *kata-te-jime*](https://youtu.be/yvOMQl1Qmow?t=835) are distinguished by one hand/wrist applying the strangle, and the other hand pinning uke by holding their belt (either attacking the guard, or the turtle).

Comment: BJA labels the bow and arrow choke as [*kata-te-jime*](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/98/).