# How are chokes/strangles classified in Judo?

Tags: judo, technique, chokes

The Kodokan has numerous materials detailing the canonical versions of their shime-waza along with several variations. However, there are a large number of competition chokes (and novel chokes imported from BJJ) which are not covered. How are these classified?

Answer (score 8):

Below is a list of chokes and how they fall into the 12 current Kodokan shime-waza classifications. Note that like with certain throws, there is often debate as to whether certain choke applications fall into one category or another (e.g. [*okuri-eri-jime* vs *kata-te-jime*](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9704/how-are-the-clock-choke-and-bow-and-arrow-choke-classified-in-judo)).

- Techniques denoted with an asterisk are not competition legal (* <sup>† ‡</sup>).
- Letter superscripts represent examples in competition ( <sup>a b c</sup> ).
- Number superscripts represent referenced materials ( <sup>1 2 3</sup> ).
- `code` denote positions technique is applied from.

---

### Kodokan shime-waza and their variations

Arm chokes:

| Kodokan name | Variations |
| --- | --- |
| **Sode-guruma-jime** | - Standard <sub>(Ezequiel choke)</sub> - Arm in Ezequiel - Baseball choke with sleeve grip - No-gi Ezequiel - Wrist-control no-gi Ezequiel |
| **Hadaka-jime** | `from behind` - Short wrist choke <sub>`Gable grip`</sub> - Rear Naked Choke <sub>`Biceps grip`</sub> `from sprawl` - Mae-hadaka-jime <sub>(Guillotine)</sub> `from pin` - North South choke* `using leg` - [Kagato-jime](https://youtu.be/yvOMQl1Qmow?t=369) <sub>(Pillory choke / Heel choke)</sub> - Ashikubi-jime <sub>(Gogoplata / Ankle choke)</sub> |

Leg chokes:

| Kodokan name | Variations |
| --- | --- |
| **Dō-jime*** |  |
| **Sankaku-jime** | - Omote-sankaku <sup>4</sup> - [Yoko-sankaku](https://youtu.be/tLe86Qiea6U?t=5064) <sup>4</sup> - Inverted triangle - Back Triangle |

Cross-collar chokes:

| Kodokan name | Variations |
| --- | --- |
| **Nami-jūji-jime** |  |
| **Gyaku-jūji-jime** | - Standard <sup>[a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/23306/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_rus2016_m_0100_0002)</sup> - [With leg assist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgEIQCHFM8M) <sup>[a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/379/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2019_m_0090_0113)</sup> |
| **Kata-jūji-jime** | - Standard - Baseball choke <sub>("Batto" jime / Ura-juji-jime)</sub> - Brabo choke - Tomoe-jime <sup>5</sup> - Collar and arm choke |

Collar chokes:

| Kodokan name | Variations |
| --- | --- |
| **Okuri-eri-jime** <sup>[a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/41546/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gp_hun2018_w_0057_0060)</sup> | `from behind` - okuri-eri-jime - Collar and arm choke <sup>3</sup> `from sprawl` - [Tawara-jime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bj1GkwERb6w) <sup>11</sup> <sub>(Inverted)</sub> - Koshi-jime <sub>(Yoko-jime / Clock choke)</sub> <sup>[a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/7355/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_aze2019_w_0048_0017)</sup> - Bow-and-Arrow choke <sup>[a](http://www.judo.or.jp/p/32969) [b](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/15144/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gp_chn2018_m_0066_0050) [c](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/15144/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_ger2019_m_0066_0063) [d](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/3637/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2018_w_0063_0055)</sup> → (with leg assist) → (Rolling entry) <sub>(Kaiten- / Oten- / British choke)</sub><sup>1</sup> <sup>[a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/1787/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2015_m_0066_0013) [b](https://seikosportslink.com/dev/judo/results.html?i=12018012&s=JU&d=JU&g=W&e=048&c=01) [c](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/1787/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2015_m_0066_0013)</sup> `from pin` - Jigoku-jime → Ashi-kake-jigoku-jime <sub>(with leg assist)</sub> `Loop chokes` - Kote-jime <sup>2 4 [a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/3787/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2017_w_0057_0055)</sup> <sub>(Kote- / Ude-shibori / Ushiro-kata-ha-jime)</sub> - [Nezumi-tori](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkfGAyBXsCY) <sub>(Loop choke grabbing leg)</sub> → Gator roll <sup>[a](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGHIKLC7Spk)</sup> |
| **Kata-te-jime** | - Kyo-jime <sub>(Breadcutter choke holding belt)</sub> <sup>[a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/9383/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gp_hun2018_w_0078_0007) [b](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/13218/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_ger2019_w_0052_0049) [c](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/13218/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gp_hun2019_w_0052_0019)</sup> - Itachi-jime <sub>(Loop choke holding belt)</sub> <sup>[a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/240/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen_teams2017_m_0073_0019)</sup> `Leg/collar choke` - Kata-te-kata-ashi-jime <sup>[a](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/13608/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_ger2018_w_0078_0024)</sup> - Ashi-jime <sub>(Canto choke)</sub> |
| **Tsukkomi-jime** | - Thrust choke - Necktie-jime |
| **Kata-ha-jime** | - Standard <sup>[a](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/72680/Musa_MOGUSHKOV_RUS_Masashi_EBINUMA_JPN_U73_Grand_Slam_Dusseldorf_2019)</sup> - [Inverted](https://youtu.be/yvOMQl1Qmow?t=819) <sub>(from sprawl)</sub> - Ōten-jime <sub>(Rolling entry)</sub> <sup>5</sup> |
| **Ryo-te-jime** | - Standard - Kani-jime <sup>‡</sup> <sub>(with leg assist)</sub> |

---

## Non-Kodokan chokes

| Technique | Variations |
| --- | --- |
| [Arm triangle](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9606/how-are-arm-triangle-chokes-classified-in-judo) | `From sprawl` - D'Arce choke → Ungvári turnover - Anaconda choke → Gator roll - Peruvian necktie‡ `From pin` - Kata-gatame - North-South choke <sub>`Arm in`</sub> - Von Flue choke |
| Body compressions | - Kesa-gatame - Uki-gatame / Knee on belly |
| Ashi-jime | - Kagato-jime <sub>`pulling lapels`</sub> - Neck scissors<sup>‡</sup> - Shin choke |
| Suso-jime | - Gerbi choke† - Baseball choke |
| Obi-jime† |  |

---

---

**Notes:**

<sup>**1.** Rolling entry sometimes referred to as *kaiten-jime / oten-jime*. Often misspelled ["othen-jime"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cSVcUJI98CIC&pg=PA61&dq=%22othen+jime%22), presumably from misreading "oh-ten" (大転, "big turn") as "o-then".</sup>
<sup>**2.** *Ude-shibori* seems to be just an alternate reading of the same characters for *ude-jime* (reading 絞 as *shiboru* as opposed to *shimeru*).</sup>

**Sources:**

<sup>**3.** [*Jiu-Jitsu University*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xL2ROQAACAAJ), Saulo Ribeiro (2008)</sup>
<sup>**4.** *Fighting Judo*, Katsuhiko Kashiwazaki (1984)</sup>
<sup>**5.** *Ma méthode de judo*, Mikonosuke Kawaishi (1952)</sup>
<sup>**6.** [*Komlock! Judo newaza of Koji Komuro*](https://books.apple.com/gb/book/%E5%B0%8F%E5%AE%A4%E5%AE%8F%E4%BA%8C-%E6%9F%94%E9%81%93%E5%9B%BA%E6%8A%80%E6%95%99%E6%9C%AC/id986257130) (2012) ([video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAPF531hFgI))</sup>
<sup>**7.** [*Judo Encyclopedia*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/%E6%9F%94%E9%81%93%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%8B%E5%85%B8.html?id=TkS_AAAACAAJ) (1999)</sup>
<sup>**8.** [*Kodokan Judo Video Series Vol. 3 - Katame-waza: Various Techniques and their Names*](https://youtu.be/yvOMQl1Qmow) (1994)</sup>
<sup>**9.** [*"Introduction to Judo Shime-Waza"*](https://www.e-hon.ne.jp/bec/SA/Detail?refShinCode=0100000000000032468579&Action_id=121&Sza_id=F3) - Baseball Magazine, Katsuhiko Kashiwazaki, Koji Komuro (2010)</sup>
<sup>**10.** *Newaza of Kashiwazaki* (1998) ([video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLe86Qiea6U))</sup>
<sup>**11.** [*Canon of Judo*](https://ironwolf008.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/canon-of-judo-by-k-mifune.pdf), Kyuzo Mifune ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKBQXrICfrE))</sup>

<sup>**-** [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/絞め技](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%9E%E3%82%81%E6%8A%80)</sup>

**Fouls:**

> <sup>***** It is never allowed to hold an osaekomi just around the head/neck without control of at least one arm.</sup>

> <sup>**†** To apply shime-waza using either your own or your opponent’s belt or bottom of the jacket or using only the fingers.</sup>

> <sup>**‡** To apply leg scissors to the opponent’s trunk (dojime), neck or head (scissor with crossed feet, while stretching out the legs). In shime-waza (e.g. ryote -jime) it is forbidden to use the legs to assist the grip.</sup>

<sup>- [IJF Sport and Organisation Rules](https://www.ijf.org/documents)</sup>

Comment: What's an arm-in North-South choke? Every N-S choke I know is specifically arms-out by design.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I don't think it's a very common submission, but here it is demo'd transitioning from side-control: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3W182KibtP0

Comment: Note: add section on nomenclature of shine-waza and how this has differed historically from nage-waza (single example technique names picked as umbrella term for many (cf ma méthode de judo) others, name doesn't necessarily characterise all such variants etc)