# Non-kodokan throws in the BJA syllabus?

Tags: judo, terminology, throwing, competition

The BJA syllabus lists a number of non-kodokan names for throws. Some of them are clearly names for common competition variants,<sup>1</sup> but some I have never heard of e.g. [*ashi-dori*](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/90/), which looks to me like [kuchiki-taoshi](https://www.reddit.com/r/judo/comments/bdoyzi/is_there_a_difference_between_kuchiki_taoshi_and/).

What is the origin of these technique names?

| BJA technique | Kodokan technique | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Kata-uchi-ashi-dori](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/90/) | Kuchiki-taoshi | Single leg grabbing from *the inside* |
| [Uchi-kibisu-gaeshi](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/98/) | Kibisu-gaeshi | Ankle pick from *the inside* |
| [Soto-kibisu-gaeshi](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/90/) | Kibisu-gaeshi | Ankle pick from *the outside* |
| [Soto-ashi-dori-ouchi-gari](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/98/) | Ouchi-gari | Ouchi-gari performed *after a single leg grabbed from the outside* |
| [Kata-hiza-te-ouchi-gake-ashi-dori](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/103/) | Ouchi-gari / Kuchiki-taoshi | Ouchi-gari, finished with kuchiki-taoshi |
| [Yoko-kata-guruma-otoshi](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/96/) | Yoko-otoshi | A *drop* "kata guruma" |

---

1. [*Yoko-tomoe-nage*](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/102/), *morote-seoi-nage*, and *te-guruma* are well established [unofficial] names for other throw variants. The following names are new to me though:

   - [*ryo-hiza-seoi-otoshi*](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/108/) is a "drop knee" seoi otoshi
   - [*morote-eri-seoi-nage*](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/79/) is a seoi-nage with a two-handed lapel grip
   - [*kata-eri sode-tsuri-komi-goshi*](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/113/) is a sode with a sleeve and collar grip (as opposed to double sleeve?)
   - [*ko-uchi-gake-mata-maki-komi*](https://www.britishjudo.org.uk/_digitaldocs/KyuGradeSyllabus/116/) is a kouchi-makikomi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are indeed a proposed classification for competition variants. It was devised by then director of the British Judo Association Roy Inman in 2005, hence the inclusion of leg-grab techniques:

> All judo techniques have their variations. For example, the 'circle throw'
> (tomoe-nage) may be performed either in the traditional way or to the
> side. This raises the issue of whether the two methods should be named
> as separate techniques. One school of thought is that they are simply
> variations on the same technique, while the other presents the view that,
> **although the basic principle of the two variations may be similar, the
> different grip or direction of movement justifies them being regarded as
> distinct techniques** (in this case, the 'circle throw to the side' should be
> called yoko-tomoe-nage).
> ...
> This presentation supports the case for specifying and naming contest
> waza that have previously only been recognised as variations of the
> established techniques. The rationale for this is that it will assist coaches
> in the teaching and demonstration of contest techniques. To give an
> example; **any leg-grabbing action** (one of the highest scoring actions in
> major tournaments) **will be termed simply 'ashi-dori'**, but the specific
> variation used may require different direction of force and/or hand
> placement.
> ...
> **The names used to describe the techniques in this research poster are
> not intended to be definitive, merely indicative.** The paper proposes that
> appropriate bodies such as the International judo Federation or the
> Kodokan should look towards expanding the number of officially
> recognised techniques and addressing the issue of the correct names rests
> with them.
> ...
> [image]

- [SHIN-KOKUSAI-SHIAIWAZA

  (Classification of Innovative International Competition Techniques)](https://www.soton.ac.uk/%7Ejudo/bja/IJFPRESENTATION2005.pdf), Roy Inman OBE 8th Dan (2005)

The apparent renaming of *Kuchiki-taoshi* to *kata-ashi-dori*, while retaining *kibisu-gaeshi*, was done presumably to use only explicitly descriptive names (and not [metaphorical ones](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/etymology-of-yama-arashi)). I presume *yama-arashi* and *tsubame-gaeshi* would similarly be relabelled "kata-eri-harai-goshi" and "de-ashi-gaeshi" if they were included. *Tomoe-nage* is ubiquitous enough to have escaped such renaming.

Similar variant classification can be seen in the BJA terms for katame-waza:

- *mune-gatame*
- [*koshi-jime*](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9704/how-are-the-clock-choke-and-bow-and-arrow-choke-classified-in-judo/9706#9706)
- *kata-te-ashi-koshi-jime*