# The name of a throw where the tori starts from a headlock

Tags: judo, throwing, defense, identification

I saw this throw demonstrated earlier today in a children's judo class. The tori starts in a headlock (or perhaps puts their own head into one), pushes their inside arm through to grab at the back of the uke, and then steps through to catch their ankle. As the uke goes over backwards, the tori does a breakfall over the top of the uke (or to the side of their head if they're trying to be gentle).

The teacher didn't know the name of this throw, and said that it wasn't in the Kodokan set. He was unsure if there is a formal name for it.

Does this have a name? Most of the headlock throws I've found on Youtube look very different and have the person performing the headlock completing the throw. It seems like it should be sutemi waza, but the lists of sutemi I can find don't have anything that sounds/looks like it.

[image]

1. Tori (red) is in headlock (or allows himself to be put in one) by uke (blue). Tori is facing away from camera, uke facing camera. Tori's right leg will step between uke's legs.
2. Tori's right arm is still in front of uke, but tori shoots (squirms?) his right arm through to grab uke behind his back (or in the judo-illegal version, grabbing at the uke's right leg).
3. Tori's right foot shoots through and catches uke's right foot. At the same time, tori pushes forward so uke falls backwards, balance having been broken. Uke lands on back, and tori breakfall/rolls either to the side of his head (or in the mean version), right over the uke.

Comment: Sounds like some variant of Yoko-guruma - a standard technique against headlock - but it is impossible to tell without further details.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking It seems similar to Yoko-guruma, but rather than rolling to the side, the tori was definitely pushing the uke backwards onto their backs, and rolling over the top of them. Does variation allow for that much difference, or would they just give it a new name?

Comment: Ahh, a guillotine (front headlock).

Comment: I found this video, and I think that this is the same throw: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECBlj3DG5pQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a [*kouchi-makikomi*](https://youtu.be/9XheHBOJEdo). In this video's variation, tori is first entering for a *sode-tsurikomi-goshi*, and tori's head ends up in a similar position to a front headlock. There is no requirement that uke have a front headlock hold for the throw to be classified as a *kouchi-makikomi*.

The key classification elements to a *kouchi-makikomi* are:

1. reaping of uke's leg from the inside, with a small leg motion (*kouchi*, as opposed to *ouchi*)
2. wrapping and falling

[*Kouchi-makikomi* is on the Kodokan list of techniques, as of 2017](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/8535/5961). Before that time it would just have been called a sacrifice version of *kouchi gari*.

Comment: Thank you. This does indeed look like it. I'm 80% certain this is it (though the teacher was of the opinion that it wasn't a Kodokan throw). I won't get a chance to discuss it with him in the foreseeable future (spring break meant no class next weekend, and coronavirus probably means none before summer break, ugh). Thank you once again.

Comment: @JohnO Putting all naming aspects aside, the technique sounds like being a really bad idea against this kind of headlock, speaking from a self-defense perspective. The risk for the neck seems extraordinarily high to me.

Comment: @JohnO It is a mystery to me how the Kodokan decides upon which throws are on their list and which are not. It was also very surprising that they changed their minds at all and decided to recognize kouchi makikomi; it is not at all surprising to me that an instructor would not keep up to date on something they never expect to happen. Kouchi makikomi was always distinctive enough to warrant its own name when trying to talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

If the uke go first on his butt and then flat on his back (rear ward) it is sutemi waza (Ko uchi makikomi).