# What is the name of this throw that starts from a failed guillotine?

Tags: throwing, identification, defense

In [this video](https://youtu.be/ECBlj3DG5pQ), a bully throws a punch at a student. They go out of frame for a second, and when they come back the bully has wrapped an arm around the student's head as if he were going for a guillotine choke (a.k.a. front headlock). The student throws the bully using the arm wrapped around his neck. I want to learn how to do this throw, but I don't know what it's called. What is its name, and what art is it most likely from?

---

<sup>**Related:** another front headlock counter throw: [The name of a throw where the tori starts from a headlock](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9777/the-name-of-a-throw-where-the-tori-starts-from-a-headlock)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a suplex (*ura-nage* in judo terminology). Since standing headlocks are illegal in judo, it is rarely taught from this position, but here is an example of a mechanically similar belly-to-belly version from a bear-hug:

[image]

- [Front Ura nage - Shintaro Higashi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_lg31MrUps)

Note a front headlock/standing guillotine is generally a **very weak position** to be in, and while this counter is [occasionally](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypewy56gUoM) [seen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbgyoCqhAzE) in MMA matches, the person performing the front headlock will in most cases be the one controlling any takedowns e.g:

- [Wrestling front headlock to suplex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kE6zUCwtw5Q)